# How can I've a VS project in production and any correction made to it be "automatically" transposed to a new project that is in a development stage?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, azure-devops

I have a project developed in Visual Studio 2013 and connected to Visual Studio Online to manage the sources. This project is already in a production environment and from time to time it needs to be patched.
Now, the same project will have a second development phase.

My idea is to have 2 projects: the one that is already in production and sometimes needs to be patched because someone finds an error and another project with the same sources to start the new development.

But this idea it seems not a very good one, because if the first project needs to be patched I’d like that patch would “automatically” added to the new project

Comment: Have a look at Branching and Merging: https://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/